# Have a list with 10 things in Python and show 9 items, and then the next time it shows, show the item not shown before

Tags: python, random

I have a list of 10 words in words.txt

```
import random
with open("words.txt") as f:
    words = random.sample([x.strip() for x in f], 9)

grouped = [words[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]
for l in grouped:
    print ("").join("{:<10}".format(x) for x in l)
```

I need to show the list with 9 of the items in the list, and then re print the list with one of the items replaced with the 10th item in the list.

Is this possible. 
As I show in the code above, I import 9 of the words - each item is on a different line in words.txt.

Comment: Well, to show the missing item you'll need to read the whole file.  Why not read it into a list ( the [x.strip() for x in f] comprehension you currently have), sample it and print the sample, and then print the whole list?

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle the list, and pick the first 9 (they'll be in random order), then replace one of the items with the remaining item:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    words = [x.strip() for x in f]

random.shuffle(words)
first_9 = words[:9]
last = words[-1]

# ...

words[random.randrange(9)] = last
```

This first reads *all* words from the file, and uses [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) to put all items in random order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    myWords = [words.strip() for words in f]
random.shuffle(myWords)   
for word in range(len(myWords)-1):
    print(word) # prints 9 words
randomWord=randint(0,8)
myWords[randomWord]=myWords[9]
for items in myWords:
    print(items)
```

Comment: `file.readlines()` *includes the newlines*, you need to strip them. Why are you using a `range()` when a loop over `myNames[:-1]` would do here?

Comment: I fixed the words.strip() thing, and I'm using range because I'm still a beginner in python, and I didn't know about what you just did. I'm just trying to help him the best I can.

Comment: Yup, and I am giving you feedback on how you can improve your Python further.